# Is it possible to use Community Builder with a very customized Service Cloud platform?

Tags: community

So from my understanding of Community Builder, it's an intuitive tool to let users customize a Community page for customers. However, if a Salesforce platform is extremely customized (think 80% custom and 20% native functionality), and I have a a lot of custom objects that I want the user to see their data on, is it possible to just use Community Builder? In other words, is there a way to pull in customized objects the "Lightning Components" into the "Page Editor" in Community Builder to drag/drop onto the page?

I have looked at this page and it seems that Community Builder is just a very basic tool that functions very well with native Salesforce objects, but when it comes to customized platforms, it's a bit trickier: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=communities_sites_which.htm&language=en_US

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Community builder is a basic tool to quickly live the community for Service.

It has predefined set of components/pages which can be used to insert comment, show recent comments, access to knowledge articles etc. with various intuitive themes.

If you have a lot of customizations and need to access custom object you will have to go with custom vforce development. In future, community may have draggable lightning components by which you can build a page but for this time custom visualforce will help only.